# Kubernetes CI/CD Tool/Utility

Tags: continuous-integration

Could anyone please help me? Is there any opensource tool or utility that does both CI and CD (basically CI/CD automation) for docker images build and push/deployment in Kubernetes POD? 
Appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to take a look at open source GitLab and review the following articles:

- [CI/CD pipeline with Auto Deploy to Kubernetes using
  GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/09/21/how-to-create-ci-cd-pipeline-with-autodeploy-to-kubernetes-using-gitlab-and-helm/)
- [Deploy Private GitLab Server within Jelastic
  PaaS](https://jelastic.com/blog/private-gitlab-server-auto-installation/)

Hope it helps.